# Stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server conversion before inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that does manipulation of parameter passed in before inserting it into my table. One of the columns in my table is called `DATE_CHANGED` and basically what I gg to do here is to change a passed date parameter like December 1st 2017 to 20171201. This is an `int` value.

I wrote a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE date_generate
     @startDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DATE_KEY INT

    @DATE_KEY = CONVERT(INT, FORMAT(@startDate, 'YYYYMMDD')

    INSERT INTO table date_key = @DATE_KEY
END
```

However I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '@DATE_KEY

Are local variable declared only used for SQL query statement like

```
select * 
from table 
where date_key = @DATE_Key?
```

Comment: SET @DATE_KEY = ...

Comment: You can not pass date as int

Comment: Why would you be storing dates as integers?  Why would you have rows in a table that only store a single date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one error.

- Use SET to assign values to a variable.
- Have a look at INSERT statement too.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE date_generate
    @startDate date
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DATE_KEY int;
        SET @DATE_KEY = CONVERT(int, format(@startDate, 'YYYYMMDD'));
        INSERT INTO DATE_CHANGED (date_key) 
        VALUES (@DATE_KEY);
    END
```

Comment: Might want to include the column name DATE_CHANGED

Comment: Uh, that is not the column name.

Comment: Was able to do with this!

Answer (score 1):

This seems really strange.  You don't even need a local variable.  Based on your code, you could write:

```
create procedure date_generate (
    @startDate date
) as
begin
    insert into table (date_key)
        values ( convert(int, format(@startDate, 'YYYYMMDD')) );
end;  -- date_generate
```

Or, I might write:

```
create procedure date_generate (
    @startDate date
) as
begin
    insert into table (date_key)
        values ( year(@startDate) * 10000 + month(@startDate) * 100 + day(@startDate) );
end;
```

Why you would have a table with a single date on each row doesn't really make sense to me.  Why you would be storing that "date" as an integer also doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you sure about that math?

Comment: You want me to just edit your posts if I see a problem?

Comment: @Paparazzi . . . The site allows editing of posts, which I definitely support for making small fixes.  I often do it when I can't quite upvote the answer because there is some relatively small problem.  On a related subject, I freely admit that I would upvote many more answers if the code were nicely indented and looked clean.

Comment: @Paparazzi . . . Without starting a religious war, I cringe when lines start with commas and semicolons, but I wouldn't put you in the category of sloppy coding.

Comment: Friendly banter.   I do that so I can comment out and not violate syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, your stored procedure accepts a DATE as a parameter, but you need to do an INSERT with an INT.

You can easily convert a DATE to a VARCHAR and then to a INT, this way:

```
DECLARE @DateASInt INT = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @startDate, 112) AS INT);
```

So, your stored procedure will be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE date_generate
    @startDate date
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO date_key
            VALUES (CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @startDate, 112) AS INT));
    END
```